# WPF При применении стиля на кнопки страницы она становятся невидимыми

Tags: c#, wpf, button, style, visual-studio-2017

Соответственно в заголовке проблема описана. Код разумеется прилагаю.
Стиль должен применяться к всем кнопкам в приложении. Важно, что на окна как раз стиль применяется корректно и кнопки не пропадают и не становятся невидимыми, в то время как на страницах они как раз становятся прозрачными, но разумеется остаются функциональными

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Button.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1900ACFF"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF00ACFF"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

До применения стиля
[image: До применения стиля]

И после
[image: После применения]

Comment: @FoggyFinder Чтож, кнопки то появились, но стиль более не работает.

Comment: @HomidWay: Вангую, что вы задали жёсткий Background. Задавайте Background тоже в стиле.

Comment: @VladD Чтож, да проверил, действительно дело в этом. Спасибо за помощь, буду значит выкручиватся.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суммируя дискуссию в комментариях:

Триггеры лучше класть в стиль, т. к. перекрывая шаблон, вы перекрываете всё «изображение» контрола. Поскольку сеттеры в шаблоне имеют меньшую силу, чем непосредственные, нужно класть их тоже в сеттер.

Итого:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Trigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1900ACFF"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF00ACFF"/>
            </Trigger.Setters>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```